# A tool to convert PostgreSQL database dumps between versions?

Tags: postgresql

On different computers/servers we have different versions of PostgreSQL installed and can't upgrade all of them yet.

Are there any tools which would allow to convert a database dump from the newer PostgreSQL version to an older one?

Comment: When going down Postgresql version have to dump using the P option plain sql file.  the other option is dump the ttables  as CSV and use copy

Comment: You can use `pg_dump` from the older versions.

Comment: I tried dumping as plain SQL, but there are still errors when importing to the newer versions related to incrementing of primary keys and others (not the simple CREATE TABLE, INSERT, UPDATE)

Comment: how far back of version are you going to a newer version,  can you supply the specific error and sql that causes the error

Comment: I was trying to dump the database with v12 and execute the SQL in v9. Some of the errors were related to primary keys (I don't have the output log by my side).

Comment: But if a tool for converting backups exists, or if there are some parameters for backwards compatibility, then the exact errors wouldn't matter.

Comment: that is going back pretty far,  there have been significant changes that will break backwards compatibility,  There are no flags or options to deal with this.  The only option is dump with no data modify the sql file,  then dump data only,  that should get you around the problem

Comment: Thanks. I will have this in mind. If you write this as an answer, I can accept it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Are there tools or options to create a pg_dump file that is compatible to earlier versions of PostgreSQL*

No there are no options or tools to create a backwards compatible pg_dump files.

Depending on how far back the version the data needs to be ported to the dump file may work there is no guarantee

A work around this limitation  would be run pg_dump using the `-P --plain` and `--schema-only`  modify the  resulting SQL file to make it compatible.

Restore the file.

Then run `pg_dump` again using `-P --plain` and `-a --data-only` options then restore the file.